# Non-existence of Lebesgue probability densities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, density-function

A standard result taught in mathematical statistics courses is that the multivariate gaussian only has a density if the covariance matrix is non singular: i.e. if $X \sim N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $\Sigma$ is nonsingular, then the (Lebesgue) density is given by
$$
f(x) = (2\pi)^{-p/2} |\Sigma|^{-1/2} \exp (-1/2 (x-\mu)^T \Sigma (x-\mu)).
$$
Given an i.i.d. sample from a univariate Gaussian: $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim N(\mu, 1)$, and taking $\bar{X}$ be the sample average, it is straight forward to show that $(X_1,\dots,X_n)|\bar{X} \sim N(\bar{X} 1_n, I_n - n^{-1}1_n1_n^T) $ where $1_n$ is the $n$-dimensional vector of ones, and $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Here it is straight forward to see that the covariance matrix is rank deficient and so $X|\bar{X}$ does not have a Lebesgue density.

My question is: more generally (in non Gaussian settings say), how can I verify whether a Lebesgue density exists for a given random vector? Is it sufficient compute the covariance matrix and verify that it is full rank? or are there cases where the covariance is full rank but the Lebesgue density still does not exist?

Comment: The covariance matrix isn't sufficient; e.g. a Bernoulli random variable has positive variance, but no density.

Comment: The general answer to your question is basically the Radon-Nikodym theorem. However, it, probably, is not what you are interested in.

Comment: @Adam I meant for continuous r.v.s where this is an issue - in the bernoulli case the distribution of $X|\bar{X}$ is easier to reason about

Comment: @Matsmir could you add some discussion on how to use the RN theorem here to verify that the density doesn't exist? Say in the gaussian case for $X|\bar{X}$?

Comment: @WeakLearner I suppose that non-existence for Gaussian case and singular covariance matrix can be proved by observing that the distribution is concentrated fully on a non-trivial subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ that has zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @WeakLearner My first comment was designed to say that without any assumptions you have RN theorem which gives a criterion for the existence of a density. From my experience in measure theory I can say that you can't do any better without some non-trivial assumptions on your measures. Covariance matrix does not seem to do much in this case, as was shown in the comment by Adam.